# Assembly Code Instructions

Tags: assembly, x86

What does the operation

`movl (%esi, %ecx,4), %eax` do?

To my understanding it would store in `%eax` the equivalent of `%ecx * 4 + %esi`.

Answer (score 3):

It's equivalent to the following in Intel syntax:

```
mov eax,[esi + ecx*4]
```

What it will do is read 32 bits from memory at the address formed by `esi + ecx*4` and put that value in `eax`.

Comment: Note that you can get `objdump` to output Intel syntax with `objdump -d -M intel`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are write.
It is called as the *index addressing* mode.

It's syntax is:

```
<constant1/label> (%reg1, %reg2, constant2)
```

i.e. either `constant1` or `label` without `<` & `>`.

`%reg1` and `%reg2` must be GPRs.
`<constant1/label>` is optional.
`%reg1` is optional.

It results in: `constant1 + %reg1 + %reg2 * constant2`

Generally, `constant1 or label` and `%reg1` are used for the base address of an array. And `%reg2` & `constant2` are used for the index.

**For example:**

Let's say, you have a global array:

```
.section .data
    .globl   arr
    .type    arr,    @object
    .size    arr,    20
    .align   4
arr:
    .long    10, 20, 30, 40, 50
```

Then you may write...

```
movl    $2,    %eax                # Move the index into %eax
movl    arr( , %eax, 4),    %edx
```

This means: `%edx = arr + %eax * 4`. i.e. Base address + 8 bytes.
You may think of it like `%edx = arr[2]`

Generally,

If you have a global array having a lable, then you use `label` for the base address.
If you have a local array, then you use the `%reg2` fot the base address.
If you have a global structure containing array, then you use both `label` of the structure + `%reg2` containing the byte-offset of the member array.

That's what happens generally... but it depends on the situation...